# Is there any way to make each line end with semicolon and after that one line space on richtextbox?

Tags: c#

When I run below code I am getting the result like below, which has no semicolon and one line break for each line on richtextbox. and the last line has two semicolon.... is there any way to make each line ending with semicolon and after that one line space on richtextbox?

```
using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand(myCommand, conn1))
{
    using (OracleDataReader reader = crtCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
         while (reader.Read())
         {
             if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
             {
                 richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                 richTextBox1.AppendText(reader[0].ToString().TrimEnd('\r', '\n', ' ') + ";");
                 richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

**Result:**

```
ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" ADD ("FIELD_A3" DATE)

ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" DROP ("FIELD_A6")

ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" MODIFY ("FIELD_A2" VARCHAR2(50))

ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" MODIFY ("FIELD_A4" NUMBER(5,2) DEFAULT 0)

ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" MODIFY ("FIELD_A4" NULL)

ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" MODIFY ("FIELD_A5" NOT NULL ENABLE);

;
```

**Expected Result:**

```
ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" ADD ("FIELD_A3" DATE);

ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" DROP ("FIELD_A6");

ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" MODIFY ("FIELD_A2" VARCHAR2(50));

ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" MODIFY ("FIELD_A4" NUMBER(5,2) DEFAULT 0);

ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" MODIFY ("FIELD_A4" NULL);

ALTER TABLE "TBL_A" MODIFY ("FIELD_A5" NOT NULL ENABLE);
```

Comment: What is the value of `myCommand`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following and see if that works:

```
using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand(myCommand, conn1))
                    {
                        using (OracleDataReader reader = crtCommand.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
                                {
                                    richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", Environment.NewLine, reader[0].ToString().TrimEnd('\r', '\n', ' '),";", Environment.NewLine));

                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you have just two results. The first is the whole text, the second is just empty string.

Suggest you debug it to prove it with break points and local variables:

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
var text = reader.GetString(0);
//breakpoint on next line and inspect text
richTextBox1.AppendText(text.TrimEnd('\r', '\n', ' ') + ";");
richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: What didn't work? Are you getting 2 results as @weston suggested? This does seem to be the most likely scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that everybody else here are right, you only need to perform one `Read()` operation.
It's not exactly an answer to your question's title, but it is probably what you need.

Just to clarify, I believe it's wrong to use the code below, and you should rather clear to yourself what exactly is the `OracleDataReader`, and what exactly the `Read()` method performs.

```
        using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand(myCommand, conn1))
        {
            using (OracleDataReader reader = crtCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                reader.Read();
                string[] splitted = reader[0].ToString().Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                foreach (string line in splitted)
                {
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + line.Trim() + ";" + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will provide the desired result:

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0} ;\r\n" + Environment.NewLine, reader[0]));
```

Here you are formatting a string as a whole,adding the object and the desired characters,transforming all process in 1 single line .
With this your code will be like this:

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
{
     richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0} ;\r\n" + Environment.NewLine, reader[0]));         
}
```

Comment: Your answer triggered the low quality post filter, you may want to add some detail/explanation

Comment: thanks,i really dont know why,its really self-explanatory i think,but thanks again apaul.

Comment: Short answers tend to trip the auto-filter and a little more explanation never hurts.

Comment: Honestly I have no background in c#, just found your answer in the low quality review queue...